# How can I compare an expected value to log transformed data?

Tags: t-test, data-transformation, expected-value, lognormal-distribution

For a school project I need to show that the data I was given does not match the expected value found in literature. My data is the diametre of 150 particles and the distribution is pretty close to lognormal. It is required that I transform the data (take the logarithm) and then perform a t-test.

> Perform a 1-sample t-test on the transformed data to show the value from literature does not match your data. Interprete the result with regard to the original data.

I have looked everywhere, but either found no good explanation or perhaps just didn't understand it. I'm pretty sure I cant just take the logarithm of the value from literature and perform a t-test against that. So what should I do?

Comment: "I'm pretty sure I cant..." Why couldn't you? If the log of a diameter is a thing, why should you not use a t-test to compare 150 of those things against 1 fixed thing of the same kind?